# Problems Using Polymer Core Element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm testing out Google's [Polymer library](https://www.polymer-project.org/), trying to get a working Drawer Panel ([see here](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-drawer-panel)). But any advice from any core element would probably work. I followed the prescribed install process ([see here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html#using-bower)).

In just trying to get that component working, I'm coming across 2 main issues:

- By default, left panel doesn't respond to mouse clicks. However, it does hide when the width goes below 480px.
- The styling only works in Chrome (v 38.0.2125.104), not Firefox (v 33.0.2) or Safari (v 7.0.6). I thought that all these browsers provided Web Components support. And if not, that `platform.js` added Polyfill Support.
- Below is the HTML I'm using

Any directions on i) how to get this working and ii) how to get this working across browsers ?

```
   <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7">
      <style src="css/style.css"></style>
      <link href="bower_components/core-elements/core-elements.html" rel="import">
      <link href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html" rel="import">
      <core-drawer-panel>
         <core-header-panel drawer="" id="drawer-panel">
            <core-toolbar>
               <div>Side Panel</div>
            </core-toolbar>
         </core-header-panel>
         <core-header-panel main="">
            <core-toolbar>
               <div>Main Panel</div>
            </core-toolbar>
         </core-header-panel>
      </core-drawer-panel>
   </html>
```

Comment: you don't need to import core-drawer-panel.html if you already import core-elements.html (aka all core elements).

Comment: Could you give more details? That's a bit vague. "does not respond to mouse clicks" and "styling only works in.."

Comment: Sure. I actually got cross browser functionality working last night.

Comment: But if you look at the [Drawer Panel example](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-drawer-panel), clicking the button toggles the left panel in and out. That doesn't work for me, even when I try to directly *open*, *close* or *toggle*: `document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();`.

Comment: One thing to check: your platform.js script needs to be *above* the polymer html imports. (they are working on fixing that).

Comment: @Nutritioustim Thanks. Now I know what exactly isn't working all I need to solve the problem for you is more details why it isn't working. Any errors in the console? logging in the event handler? Finding out exactly what it is that's not working as expected?